# Fudge Factor in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can anyone enlighten me about the use of fudgeFactor in Matlab?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>which fudgeFactor
```

This will tell you where that function resides

```
>>edit fudgeFactor
```

This will show you the MATLAB file.  It is not in any standard install of MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks! It says that fudgeFactor is a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that fudgeFactor is a function or variable specific to your application or code base. It does not appear to be a built-in MATLAB feature.

Answer (score 1):

If it's well-documented,

```
help fudgeFactor
```

will display the documentation.  Couldn't hurt to try!

Answer (score 0):

A "fudge factor" is engineering slang for the number that you multiply your calculated result by in order to get the answer you wanted!